# IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> to IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, odata

I have an application that lets a user dynamically query any OData service and return to them the specific columns they requested inside of a grid.  After weeks of research, I ended up using [Simple.OData.Client](https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client) to query the service. In order to get data back, I have model that defines what needs to be done.  Here is what is relevant to my question:

- BaseUrl (Service address)
- ListName (table/list to query against)
- Columns (List)

  - ODataColumnPath (Path to the data I want)
  - ColumnDataType (The type of data being returned / to be cast to)
  - FriendlyName (Something friendly to use)
  - CalculationType (Enum `None, Count, Sum, Min, Max`)

Now the `ODataColumnPath` can be as simple as "ProductName" or be as complex as "Category/Product/Orders/OrderID" to return a single field or to return many.  When it returns many values I do some sort of calculation with it.

Currently I create a `DataTable` by recursively looping (while loop) through all `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>`s until I get the value(s) that I am looking for.  I then use the XML data to create the DataTable columns and then I populate the rows from the loop.  This approach works fine but I have to think there is a better way of doing this.

Now when I run the query I am looking for in LinqPad connecting directly to [a Northwind odata service](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/) I get back a `IQueryable<Anonymous>` object.

**LinqPad -> Northwind**

```
Products.Select (x => new { x.ProductID, x.ProductName, x.Category.CategoryName })
```

**Request URL**

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products()?$expand=Category&$select=ProductID,ProductName,Category/CategoryName

Using the OData library mentioned above, I get back the same data but as `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>`

**Code**

```
ODataClient client = new ODataClient(new ODataClientSettings { UrlBase = "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/", OnTrace = (a, b) => { string.Format(a, b).Dump("Trace Event"); } });
var data = await client.For("Products").Expand("Category").Select("ProductID,ProductName,Category/CategoryName").FindEntriesAsync().Dump();
```

**Request URL (From trace event)**

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products?$expand=Category&$select=ProductID,ProductName,Category/CategoryName

Now if I specify a strongly typed class, I get back the same as the `IQueryable` did (with a little extra work):

```
var strongly = (await client
    .For<Product>()
    .Expand(x => x.Category)
    .Select(x => new { x.ProductID, x.ProductName, x.Category.CategoryName })
    .FindEntriesAsync())
    .Select(x => new { x.ProductID, x.ProductName, x.Category.CategoryName })
    .Dump();
```

What I would like to get back is an anonymous list object or a dynamic object.  From there I can apply my calculations if needed.  Is there a way to dynamically define a class and pass it into the `For<T>(...)` static method?

Even though I spent weeks researching this topic to end up using Simple.OData.Client, I am open to using some other method of getting my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding [LatticeUtils AnonymousTypeUtils.cs](https://github.com/dotlattice/LatticeUtils/blob/master/LatticeUtils/AnonymousTypeUtils.cs) which creates an anonymous object from a Dictionary to create an anonymous object.
I ended up modifying the first `CreateObject` method with the following

```
public static object CreateObject(IDictionary<string, object> valueDictionary)
{
  Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in valueDictionary)
  {
      if (pair.Value != null && pair.Value.GetType() == typeof(Dictionary<string, object>))
      {
          // Create object and add
          object o = CreateObject(pair.Value as IDictionary<string, object>);
          values.Add(pair.Key, o);
      }
      else if (pair.Value != null && pair.Value.GetType() == typeof(List<IDictionary<string, object>>))
      {
          // Get first dictionary entry
          IDictionary<string, object> firstDictionary = ((IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>)pair.Value).First();

          // Get the base object
          object baseObject = CreateObject(firstDictionary);

          // Create a new array based off of the base object
          Array anonArray = Array.CreateInstance(baseObject.GetType(), 1);

          // Return like the others
          values.Add(pair.Key, anonArray);
      }
      else
      {
          values.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
      }
  }

  Dictionary<string, Type> typeDictionary = values.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value != null ? kv.Value.GetType() : typeof(object));

  Type anonymousType = CreateType(typeDictionary);

  return CreateObject(values, anonymousType);
}
```

If you strip out all of the unused methods, comments, and variables like `mutable` I ended up with 160ish lines of readable code.

In order to read the data I am still using Simple.OData.Client to get my data but I am serializing the object to JSON, creating the anonymous object, and then deserializing everything back into an `IEnumerable`.  With this I am able to process 1000 records from my OData service in about 0.35 seconds or so.

```
// Get Data
ODataClient client = new ODataClient(new ODataClientSettings { UrlBase = "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/", OnTrace = (a, b) => { string.Format(a, b).Dump("Trace Event"); } });
IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> data = await client
    .For("Products")
    .Expand("Category,Order_Details")
    .Select("ProductID,ProductName,SupplierID,CategoryID,QuantityPerUnit,UnitPrice,UnitsInStock,UnitsOnOrder,ReorderLevel,Discontinued,Category/CategoryName,Order_Details")
    .FindEntriesAsync();

// Convert to JSON
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

// Create anonymous type/object
object anonymousObject = AnonymousClassBuilder.CreateObject(data.First());

// Deserialize into type
IEnumerable enumerable = (IEnumerable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, anonymousObject.GetType().MakeArrayType());
```

I might end up creating a Fork of Simple.OData.Client and adding this to it so I don't have to serialize the object back to JSON and then back to an object.